# Bootstrap: Remove animation from transition.js

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using twitter bootstrap and the `transition.js` plugin to make a collapse like described here.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

I have two problems with it:

1. How can i remove the animation from the effect? it should instantly open and close.
2. How can i give the open panel a different background color?

Comment: you want the background color on the body or the heading of the panel?

Comment: @koala_dev both, actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the animation effect you need to override the `.collapsing` class, add this to your CSS:

```
.collapsing{
    -webkit-transition: none;
          transition: none;
}
```

Now, to style the active panel you'd need to implement some jQuery code to add a custom class when a panel is shown since by default only the panel-body container is marked with the `in` class, and you wouldn't be able to target the heading with that. Something like this should work:

```
$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse','.panel-collapse',function(e){
    $(this).closest('.panel').addClass('active').siblings('.panel').removeClass('active');
});
```

Then you can add your CSS rules as:

```
#accordion .active .panel-heading{
    background: darkgrey;
}

#accordion .active .panel-body{
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Here's a **[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/Kzzwm/1)**

*Note: don't forget to add the "active" class to the pane that is open by default (if any)